# Compute some metric using two columns of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

The top 5 rows in my data frame:

```
roster_data.head()
No.     Player         Flag  Pos    Age Ht      Wt  S/C     Exp  
27.0    Karl Alzner     ca    D     29  3-Jun   217 L/-      9   
8.0     Jordie Benn     ca    D     30  2-Jun   198 L/-      6        
41.0    Paul Byron      ca    C/LW  28  9-May   162 L/-      7  
43.0    Daniel Carr     ca    LW    26  Jun-00  193 L/-      2  
24.0    Phillip Danault ca    LW    24  1-Jun   195 L/-      3
```

Using Age and YearsExperience (EXP column), how do I calculate what player from the list started playing for the NHL at the earliest age?

I am unable to get the logic of the code.

Comment: @LevZakharov I have made the pandas dataframe more clear now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have data frame `df`:

```
df.iloc[[(pd.to_numeric(df['Age']) - pd.to_numeric(df['Exp'])).min()]]
```

Comment: I am getting an error stating that "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'"

Comment: @MJP you need to convert your columns to numeric type. Fixed.

Comment: I am getting an error again : ValueError: Unable to parse string "R" at position 14

Comment: @MJP so you have non-integer values in your column. You need to convert this columns somehow. Depends on your application logic. For example you can drop this rows.

Comment: -> roster_data['Exp'] = pd.to_numeric(roster_data['Exp'], errors = 'coerce')
-> roster_data[["Exp"]] = roster_data[["Exp"]].astype(float). Worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try:

```
start_age = roster_data['Age'] - roster_data['Exp']
min_age = start_age.min()
min_idx = start_age.argmin()
roster_data.ix[min_idx]
```

Comment: I think you would need `start_age.idxmin()` rather to get the player and not just the  age. This would return the first player, if there is multiple players, it would be `roster_data[start_age == start_age.min()]` to get all players.